# Neovim dap C++ clangd

Tags: c++, debugging, neovim, clangd

I'm having trouble configuring dap in NeoVim - after executing **:lua require’dap’.continue()** I get this error:

> Path to executable: /home/user/Projects/C++/app/E5108: Error executing lua ...l/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-dap/lua/dap.lua:385: ...nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-dap/lua/dap/session.lua:1295: Error running /hom
> e/user/Devtools/vscode-lldb: EACCES: permission denied
> stack traceback:
> [C]: in function 'trigger_run'
> ...l/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-dap/lua/dap.lua:385: in function 'run'
> ...l/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-dap/lua/dap.lua:319: in function 'cb'
> ...hare/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-dap/lua/dap/ui.lua:34: in function 'pick_if_many'
> ...l/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-dap/lua/dap.lua:313: in function 'select_config_and_run'
> ...l/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-dap/lua/dap.lua:688: in function 'continue'
> [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk

Directory with vscode-llb - user have full access for it.

> drwxrwxr-x 17 user user 4,0K dec 30 07:12pm vscode-lldb

debugging.lua

```
require("dap").adapters.lldb = {
    type = "executable",
    command = "/home/user/Devtools/vscode-lldb", 
    name = "lldb",
}

local lldb = {
    name = "Launch lldb",
    type = "lldb", -- matches the adapter
    request = "launch", -- could also attach to a currently running process
    program = function()
        return vim.fn.input(
            "Path to executable: ",
            vim.fn.getcwd() .. "/",
            "file"
        )
    end,
    cwd = "${workspaceFolder}",
    stopOnEntry = false,
    args = {},
    runInTerminal = false,
}

local dap = require('dap')
dap.configurations.cpp = {
  {
    name = 'Launch',
    type = 'lldb',
    request = 'launch',
    program = function()
      return vim.fn.input('Path to executable: ', vim.fn.getcwd() .. '/', 'file')
    end,
    cwd = '${workspaceFolder}',
    stopOnEntry = false,
    args = {},
  },
}

dap.configurations.c = dap.configurations.cpp
```

I can't find a similar problem - so I'm doing something wrong - but what? Anyone have any suggestions.

Change of folder access permissions to application, to vscode-lldb, update of plugins.